# How to handle success and error API responses with Swift Generics?

Tags: swift, generics, async-await, decodable, loopback4

I am trying to write a simple function handling authentication `POST` requests that return JWT tokens.

My [LoopBack 4](https://loopback.io/doc/index.html) API returns the token as a JSON packet in the following format:

```json
{ "token": "my.jwt.token" }
```

In case of an error, the following gets returned instead:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "name": "UnauthorizedError",
    "message": "Invalid email or password."
  }
}
```

As you can see, these types are completely different, they don't have any common properties.

I've defined the following Swift structures to represent them:

```swift
// Success
struct Token: Decodable {
  let token: String
}

// Error
struct TokenError: Decodable {
  let error: ApiError
}

struct ApiError: Decodable {
  let statusCode: Int
  let name: String
  let message: String
}
```

The signature of the authentication request that returns Swift Generics:

```swift
@available(iOS 15.0.0, *)
func requestToken<T: Decodable>(_ user: String, _ password: String) async throws -> T
```

I've been trying to unit test this function but Swift requires me to declare the type of the result up front:

```swift
let result: Token = try await requestToken(login, password)
```

This works perfectly fine for the happy path but if the authentication is unsuccessful, a `The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.` error gets thrown. I can certainly do-catch it but I haven't been able to cast the result to my `TokenError` type in order to access its properties.

I have come across a few threads on StackOverflow where the general advice is to represent the success and error types by a common protocol but I've had no luck with that either due to a conflict with the `Decodable` protocol that the response types already conform to.

So the question is whether it is possible to work with both success and error `result` variables returned by my `requestToken` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most natural way, IMO is to throw ApiErrors, so that they can be handled in the same way as other errors. That would look like this:

Mark ApiError as an Error type:

```
extension ApiError: Error {}
```

Now you can decode Token directly, and it will throw ApiError if there's an API error, or DecodingError if the data is corrupted. (Note the use of `try?` in the first decode and `try` in the `else` decode. This way it throws if the data can't be decoded at all.)

```
extension Token: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case token
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self),
           let token = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token)
        {
            self.init(token: token)
        } else {
            throw try TokenError(from: decoder).error
        }
    }
}

// Usage if you want to handle ApiErrors specially

do {
    try JSONDecoder().decode(Token.self, from: data)
} catch let error as ApiError {
    // Handle ApiErrors
} catch let error {
    // Handle other errors
}
```

---

Another approach is to keep ApiErrors separate from other errors, in which case there are three possible ways `requestToken` can return. It can return a Token, or it can return a TokenError, or it can throw a parsing error. Throwing an error is handled by `throws`. Token/TokenError require an "or" type, which is an enum. This could be done with a [Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result#), but that might be a little confusing, since the routine also throws. Instead I'll be explicit.

```
enum TokenRequestResult {
    case token(Token)
    case error(ApiError)
}
```

Now you can make this Decodable by first trying to decode it as a Token, and if that fails, try decoding it as a TokenError and extracting the ApiError from that:

```
extension TokenRequestResult: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let token = try?
            container.decode(Token.self) {
            self = .token(token)
        } else {
            self = .error(try container.decode(TokenError.self).error)
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, you just need to switch:

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(TokenRequestResult.self, from: token)

switch result {
case .token(let token): // use token
case .error(let error): // use error
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks for your quick and detailed response, Rob. I really like your first suggestion as I think it's more elegant than the other. Still, I've had no luck with it as the code breaks on the `if` statement in the `Token` extension (it throws `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`). I whacked a breakpoint onto that line and when I tried stepping over it, it created another "dispatch thunk of SingleValueDecodingContainer.decode" entry under one of the Network threads and that was happening over and over again. I was testing both valid and invalid requests and this would happen in both scenarios.

Comment: Sorry about that. I created an infinite loop that I should have noticed. I was testing this too quickly. Code is updated.